# In the sentence "when I last saw her..." was the word "last" used correctly? I would say " when I saw her last time..."

Tags: grammar

In the sentence "When I last saw her...", was the word "last" used correctly? I would say " When I saw her last time..." I want to know how to use the word"last".

Comment: They are both grammatical, but I would say that *when I last saw her* is much more natural. Even if you make the revision *when I saw her **the** last time*, which sounds better, I still don't think it's as natural as the first—at least not without additional context that could change that. On the other hand, *when I saw her last* (forget about *time*) sounds slightly better to me than than the first version.

Comment: was "last" used as an adverb modifying saw？

Comment: In *I **last** saw her*, it's an adverb modifying *saw*. In *I saw her* ***last time***, it's an adjective modifying *time*. In *I saw her* ***last***, depending on the interpretation, it's either an adverb modifying *saw*, or it's a verb where *she* is its subject.

Comment: You may find this reference helpful - https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86317/the-usage-of-the-word-last

Comment: “The last time ever I saw her face...”.